# EhCache Write-Behind: Removing objects after writing to Db

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa, ehcache

I'm using ehcache with write-behind in order to optimize the writing to db (through hibernate). 
My question is how do I configure ehcache to remove from the cache an element that was just written to db?
I tried several combinations of ttl and time to idle but couldnt make it work.

I need that because I found out that if element x was putWithWriter and then written to db, then if I do cache.get() then in case that the x is in the cache I get x as an unmanaged entity. 
I know that I can set ehcache to be transnational but it comes with a cost, while in most cases I dont need it. Another reason is that I'm new to ehcache and to its configuration and right now I hope for a fast solution.

Maybe I can remove them with cache.remove() in the writer, but then I'd have to explicitly lock it and it has its costs right?

So can I configure ehcache to remove elements from cache right when it writes them to db?

Thanks!